# How to take control back on a separate process in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell

I just set up a Minecraft server on my VPS for my brother and I ran it with a bash script :
`sh ./server.sh&`

This way, the server is running and I can still work on the same command line with putty. But what if I want to input commands to the Minecraft server ? How do I do get this back on the console screen :

`[10:17:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.7.10
[10:17:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[10:17:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[10:17:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[10:17:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[10:17:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[10:17:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[10:17:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 52%
[10:17:26] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 99%
[10:17:26] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (2.132s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
<input line>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with [Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).
Installation can be done via apt-get. Afterwards you just type `screen` in the prompt, start a process (even without sending it to background), close the session, and the process still keeps running.
To re-attatch to the screen-session, you just ssh back into the machine and type `screen -r`. You can also detatch from the active screen by pressing `CTRL+A` followed by `CTRL+D`.

Comment: I think this is a better and more general solution. You can even put a resume command in your .bash_profile. I have: if $(screen -ls | grep -q pts); then  screen -x; else screen -R; fi

Answer (score 6):

#### How do I get a background job into the foreground?

Use `fg`.

> **fg**
>
> Send job to foreground
>
> **Syntax**
>
> fg [PID...]
>
> **Options**:
>
> If PID is specified, the job with the specified group id is
>   put in the foreground.
>
> Send the specified job to the foreground. While a foreground job is
>   executed, fish is suspended. If no job is specified, the last job to
>   be used is put in the foreground.
>
> The PID of the desired process is usually found by using process
>   expansion.
>
> **Example**
>
> Put the job with job id 0 in the foreground:
>
> fg %0

Source [fg Send job to foreground](http://ss64.com/bash/fg.html)

Comment: Thanks mate, but now I got another problem. If I take the server proccess in the background with Ctrl+Z I have a warning from the shell :  
`[1]+  Stopped       sh /.../mineserv.sh`  
And then when I take it back to foreground with `fg`, the server warns me it is running xxxx ms behind, where xxxx is the duration for which it has been running in background. How do I get processes not to be stopped when sent to background ?

Comment: @qreon - If you type `bg` immediately after `Ctrl-z` it will run in background.

Comment: Even better, do `fg; bg` so when you Ctrl+Z out of the server, it will run `bg` automatically.